# Are context managers aware of the lines of code they contextualise?

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, contextmanager

I've used Python's context managers frequently, usually in place of some try-catch-finally type of logic. However, recently I've seen some examples of these where they go beyond the simple, and I'm trying to understand how they work. As an example, here's a pattern I've seen in some libraries

```
first = SomeClass()
second = SomeOtherClass()

with SomeContext() as c:
    first.do_calculation()
    second.do_calculation()

c.execute()
```

In these examples the context manager is somehow aware of the lines of code it contextualises without explicitly passing the variable 'c' to the methods. A concrete example can be seen in for example the [Prefect workflow engine](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect) where tasks are added to a flow which is then executed. Here's a simple example

```
from prefect import task, Flow

@task
def first(x, y):
    return x + y

@task
def second(x, y):
    return x*y


with Flow('test-flow') as flow:
    res_first = first(1, 2)
    res_second = second(res_first)

flow.run()
```

Here somehow the flow 'test-flow' becomes aware of the tasks within its context, but I really don't understand how. The example I'm most closely looking to mirror is that of [gs-quant](https://github.com/goldmansachs/gs-quant/) which has this type of logic for pricing financial derivatives

```
ir_swap = InterestRateSwap(...)  # fictive class names for brevity
eq_option = EquityOption(...)

with PricingContext(...) as p:
    ir_price = ir_swap.price()
    eq_price = eq_option.price()

print(ir_price.result(), eq_price.result())
```

Here the `PricingContext` could e.g. set market rates for another date, thus altering the return of the `.price()` call. The guides for this library mention the following:

*Note that using a PricingContext as a context manager has two extra effects:
All calls to price(), calc() are dispatched as a single request, on context manager exit. This allows for the communication overhead to be borne only once for multiple calculations.*

So, as an example, suppose I have the following code

```
class MyClass:
   def __init__(self):
       ...
 
   def calculate(self):
       ...


my_class = MyClass()
with MyContext() as c:
    my_class.calculate()
```

where I want the context to inform the logic of `.calculate()`

I'm aware one could simply pass the context manager as an argument to the method, but the libraries I mentioned don't seem to do that. I'm assuming the libraries mentioned above have some sort of (global) default manager set but I'm not sure what a good design for that would be.

I have tried to understand the logic that both prefect as gs-quant use, however their codebases are relatively dense and difficult to parse (lots of metaclasses and such)

Comment: I suspect the `@task` decorator is registering the tasks with the flow, the context manager isn't doing it by itself.

Comment: Not implicitly. See https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement to see how a `with` statement is "desugared" to a particular `try` statement. The context manager can make an object available *to* the body of the statement (via the return value of its `__enter__` method), and it can process any exception raised in the body via the arguments to its `__exit__` method, but it has no visibility into the body of the `with` statement itself.

Comment: In your first example, it's probably more accurate to say that the lines of code in the body are aware of some global state that the context manager *sets*, rather than the context manager being aware of the body of the `with` statement in anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

##### Preface

As @chepner wrote, there is no straightforward (or implicit) syntax to make this work in python, at least not at the moment. @barmar's comment was on-the-money (the docstring for `def task()`: `Decorator to designate a function as a task in a Prefect workflow.`), so if `gs-quant`'s code is a bit dense, maybe `Prefect`'s definition for [task](https://github.com/PrefectHQ/prefect/blob/cc918ea95205519e4ce1d1e1b76ae0f5a115008f/src/prefect/tasks.py) can make for an easier read (I didn't check the former myself).
Coming back to @chepner's second comment, it is not *impossible* to make the context manager be aware of underlying executions, but that would usually be much more complicated to achieve, and significantly less maintainable. So as they wrote - for most implementations (and as a general pattern), *it is* probably more accurate to say that the code in the body is aware of a setting/state which is set by the running context, not the other way around. And with this, I'll proceed to the first example of how body-code can cooperate with the context it is running in;

##### Example #1

The following file (let's call it `mul_simple.py`) shows how a context can "affect" underlying code. More accurately put, it shows how underlying code can interact with the context it is running in. In this example, `print_result` receives a textual representation, and will use the context to multiply `num` by its setting to match the text. The context manager tracks its current state (to allow context re-entry with different values), and exposes its helper function for the use of underlying code. While the context performs the multiplication itself, it can simply expose the current multiplier to a calling function for use at its own discretion.

```
def print_result(num_name, func, num):
    result = func(num).calculate()
    print(f"{num_name} is: {result}")


class Multiplier:
    _multiply_context = [1]

    @classmethod
    def get_result(cls, multiplied):
        return multiplied * cls._multiply_context[-1]

    def __init__(self, multiplier):
        self.multiplier = int(multiplier)

    def __enter__(self):
        self._multiply_context.append(self.multiplier)

    def __exit__(self, type_, value_, traceback_):
        _ = self._multiply_context.pop()
        if any(arg is not None for arg in (type_, value_, traceback_)):
            return False    # reraise


class MultipliedBase:
    def calculate(self):
        return Multiplier.get_result(self)

class MultipliedInt(int, MultipliedBase):
    pass


def main_int():
    func = MultipliedInt
    print_result("Three", func, 3)

    with Multiplier(2):
        print_result("Six", func, 3)

        with Multiplier(4):
            print_result("Sixteen", func, 4)

        print_result("Eight", func, 4)

    print_result("Five", func, 5)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_int()
```

Running this will output:

```
$ python mul_simple.py
Three is: 3
Six is: 6
Sixteen is: 16
Eight is: 8
Five is: 5
```

##### Example #2

Say we wanted to extend our context to multiply strings as well. This is one case where had we made the context aware of the body-code - we'd have to make more significant, delicate changes, to the context manager itself. Luckily we chose the other path, so no changes need be performed, only adding a new file. Let's call it `mul_str.py`:

```
from mul_simple import print_result, Multiplier, MultipliedBase

class MultipliedStr(str, MultipliedBase):
    pass


def main_str():
    func = MultipliedStr
    print_result("One", func, "One")

    with Multiplier(2):
        print_result("AbAb", func, "Ab")

        with Multiplier(4):
            print_result("FourFourFourFour", func, "Four")

        print_result("FooFoo", func, "Foo")

    print_result("Bar", func, "Bar")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main_str()
```

And running it will result in:

```
$ python mul_str.py
One is: One
AbAb is: AbAb
FourFourFourFour is: FourFourFourFour
FooFoo is: FooFoo
Bar is: Bar
```

##### Example #3

To demonstrate how this can work as a function decorator (like `@task` in Prefect), we can create a file called `mul_deco.py`, as an example:

```
from mul_simple import Multiplier

class MultiplierWithDecorator(Multiplier):

    @classmethod
    def multiply(cls, multiplier):
        def outer(func):
            def inner(*args, **kwargs):
                with cls(multiplier):
                    return cls.get_result(func(*args, **kwargs))
            return inner
        return outer


@MultiplierWithDecorator.multiply(3)
def by_six(arg):    # arg * 2 * 3
    return arg * 2


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(f"Thirty six is: {by_six(6)}")
    print(f"Forty two is: {by_six(7)}")
```

And executing it will print:

```
$ python mul_deco.py
Thirty six is: 36
Forty two is: 42
```

##### Example #4

Finally, while the context manager won't be aware of the underlying code, we can make it collect multiplication request for us to execute at a later time. With slight adjustments this can be utilized to aggregate requests over a single connection. If the contents of the file `mul_aggregate.py` are as such:

```
class MultiplyLater:
    _multiply_context = []

    @classmethod
    def add_result(cls, name, to_multiply):
        try:
            cls._multiply_context[-1]._delayed_results.append((name, to_multiply))
        except IndexError:
            raise IndexError("No active multiplication context")

    def __init__(self, multiplier):
        self.multiplier = int(multiplier)
        self._delayed_results = []

    def __enter__(self):
        self._multiply_context.append(self)
        return self

    def __exit__(self, type_, value_, traceback_):
        _ = self._multiply_context.pop()
        if any(arg is not None for arg in (type_, value_, traceback_)):
            return False    # reraise

    def get_results(self):
        return [(name, to_multiply * self.multiplier) for (name, to_multiply) in self._delayed_results]


class LaterMultiplied:
    def __init__(self, name, to_multiply):
        MultiplyLater.add_result(name, to_multiply)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    with MultiplyLater(3) as later_three:
        LaterMultiplied("Six", 2)
        LaterMultiplied("Nine", 3)
        with MultiplyLater(2) as later_two:
            LaterMultiplied("Four", 2)
            LaterMultiplied("Twelve", 6)
        LaterMultiplied("Fifteen", 5)

    for name, result in later_three.get_results():
        print(f"By 3; {name} is: {result}")
    for name, result in later_two.get_results():
        print(f"By 2; {name} is: {result}")
```

Then running it will print:

```
$ python mul_aggregate.py
By 3; Six is: 6
By 3; Nine is: 9
By 3; Fifteen is: 15
By 2; Four is: 4
By 2; Twelve is: 12
```

##### Conclusion

While this is still far from how libraries like Prefect implement their capabilities, I'm hoping this demo provides a foundation which makes some sense.

Comment: Amazing! This was exactly what I was looking for (and more still!). Thank you so much for taking your time to write such a detailed answer :)

Comment: Wow, this is absolutely awesome! Thank you for this amazing answer!